# Blocked host not fount in /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking, hosts

I have blocked some host on my system (e.g. facebook.com) but I can not find them in the hosts file. I assume I have blocked hosts elsewhere or with some program but I do not remember where/which.

I need to unblock some hosts but can not find the entries anywhere. They are not blocked in `/etc/hosts`
Any ideas?
thx

Answer (score 1):

If you have any system-wide program that blocks it, maybe you'll find some entries with grep.

```
sudo grep facebook /etc/ -rs
```

It's also possible that you've blocked hosts with a DNS service like OpenDNS. Try to change your DNS servers using Network Manager in Gnome Settings. You can use [CloudFlare's DNS](https://1.1.1.1/).

It could be a firewall as well. Look for any rules in your iptables:

```
sudo iptables -S
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The command `sudo grep facebook /etc/ -rs` found the file dnsmasq.config and I could edit the entries. ;-)